# If $X \perp Y$ holds, under what conditions would it also imply $X \perp Y \mid Z$ for another random variable $Z$?

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $X \perp Y$ holds, such that $X$ is independent of $Y$. I am wondering under what conditions might it be the case

$$
X \perp Y \mid Z
$$

for another random variable $Z$? Are there general conditions on $X,Y$ or on $Z$ that could make marginal independence hold for conditional independence for another random variable $Z$?

Comment: What if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are _mutually independent_?

Comment: @DilipSarwate It appears then the equation always holds. Is that a sufficient condition or the only one?